# <Images aren't showing on vercel

Tags: html, css, image, deployment, vercel

When I use the 'Live Server' Extension in VS Code my website looks great.

I deployed on vercel and the only thing showing are my social media buttons and the footer. Everything in between are 'alt=""' broken images. (alt="" being an example of course.)

An example of one of the lines:

```
<div class="container" id="roadmap">
    <img class="center" src="/public/images/Roadmap Button.png" 
    alt="roadmap" style="width: 50%;height: 100%; margin-left: 
    25%;">
    <img class="w-100" src="/public/images/Roadmap.png" 
    alt="roadmap">
</div>
```

My index.html, styles.css, and images folder is all in the public folder. Once again, on local server everything looks great, but when I deploy it, everything works great **except** for the images. They just won't show. **Only the alt tag will** **(alt="")**.

I also cleared my cache, and looked on different browsers and devices. Same thing. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. I am somewhat a beginner at this still. So I am going for more of a static/navigational website.

Comment: do you tried to insert the images in the folder when you put the index.html? example if you do so vercel will create a link to it — I write  ./images/1dark.jpg github pages do https://laaouatni.github.io/w11-clone/images/1dark.jpg

Comment: can you send the link of your website. so we can found the bug with devtools

Comment: Is there a build folder. If so, vercel may be using that folder to publish the site. If that's the case, check that folder and update urls accordingly. If not, go to developer tools on chrome or firefox and try different combinations and then change it in the code